# iPhone 6s question in reference to my iPad

Tags: iphone

If I sync my messages to my iPad will I get an alert on my iPhone? 
And if I delete messeges on my iPad will it delete the same messages on my iPhone?

Comment: Do you mean text messages, e-mail messages, or something else? If e-mail, what provider are you using, or which protocol (POP3 or IMAP)?

Answer (score 1):

If you sync both iPad and iPhone you will receive alerts in both the devices. While, deleting messages and conversations has to be done on each individual device separately so deleting is not synchronised.